# Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. -on api testing though jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

Sending the request through jmeter returns  - bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

Im able to send the request successfully through postman and get a valid response.
I've already put the headers in jmeter header manager as is on postman
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request is successful in Postman my expectation is that given you send the same request from JMeter you should get the same successful response.

If you cannot figure out the differences just record the request from Postman

1. [Prepare JMeter for recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxy). Start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder from the recording template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

   [image]
2. Prepare Postman for Recording

   - [Import JMeter's certificate to Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

     [image]
   - [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

     [image]
3. Run your request in Postman
4. JMeter will generate the appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

   [image]

You may also want to take a look at [How do I troubleshoot 403 errors from CloudFront?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-troubleshoot-403-errors/) AWS documentation chapter

Comment: I recorded the script as you suggested and the request was sent successfully,,thanks alot